# Woocommerce - how to disable downlodable and virtual checkbox in new product admin page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to permanently disable downloadable and virtual products from woocommerce.
How can I hide these two checkbox so my client doesn't do something wrong?
I didn't find any plugin to do this so I think that is better to hide any reference to downlodable/virtual content.

[image]

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below code in your functions.php

**Option One**

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_fonts');

function my_custom_fonts() {
 echo '<style>
 .type_box .show_if_simple {
  display: none !important;
 } 
 </style>';
}
```

One another and most proper way

**Option Two (My favorite one)**

```
add_filter( 'product_type_options', 'remove_product_types' );

function remove_product_types( $types ){

 unset( $types['virtual'] );
 unset( $types['downloadable'] );
 return $types;
}
```

**Option Three**

create admin-style.css file and add the mentioned css after php code.

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_admin_style' );
function load_admin_style() {
    wp_register_style( 'admin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin-style.css', false, '1.0.0' );//OR

}
```

Css Code

```
.type_box .show_if_simple {
  display: none !important;
 }
```

Choose any option

Comment: Very comprehensive answer, noice

Comment: Note that these options still exist in the sort options in the product list

Answer (score 0):

You'd better to remove them using `product_type_options` hook, and not with Styling. To show/hide them (and all many other fields), you can try a [WC Remove Tabs & Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-remove-tabs-and-fields/) plugin which does the job.

Comment: It is not enough to use `product_type_options` because these options also appear in the sort options in the product list

Answer (score 0):

The Above Solution is right but I have bit improved the code, **excluding PHP notices.** Add the below code in your active theme.

```
    add_filter( 'product_type_options', function( $options ) {
    // remove "Virtual" checkbox
    if( isset( $options[ 'virtual' ] ) ) {
        unset( $options[ 'virtual' ] );
    }
    // remove "Downloadable" checkbox
    if( isset( $options[ 'downloadable' ] ) ) {
        unset( $options[ 'downloadable' ] );
    }
    return $options;
} );
```

Do not **ignore the conditions on lines 3 and 9**, because if checkboxes are already removed in another place in the code (maybe in some plugin), **you will get PHP notices.**